# log JSP output to file

Tags: file, jsp

I'm not a java guy and I got some JSP code from a friend for testing purposes. 
All succes/faliure information is being output to browser, but the problem is - I'm not the one who is making the request. So

Is there any simple way to copy/redirect default output of the JSP to a file on server but still finish the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a JSP custom body tag that can capture the contents of it's body to the file after the body is processed. You would dispatch to a wrapper jsp with the capture tag and the real jsp is passed as a parameter.

Example:

```
<mytags:capture filename="file.html">

<jsp:include page="<%=request.getParameter("realpage")%>"/>

</mytags:capture>
```

Checkout online tag library :

http://www.servletsuite.com/jsp.htm

On this library I found "Postprocessor taglib" this had getContent & getContentString which can be used in you case.

http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/postproctag.htm

Comment: This sounds like what I asked for, but... I'm not a java guy as I said, and I don't get it. I'll accept Your answer if people upvote it or if I manage to understand what I have to do ;)

Comment: I have added link to JSP tag library. You Create similar or use this tag library in your JSP.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use the standard code:

```
System.out.println("message...");
```

which usually prints to **catalina.out** in Tomcat application server.